# Error when creating AWS EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am getting below error while creating EMR cluster. I am not getting any clue in google also. I gone through the given url in error also but no help. Please some one can help on this.

**ERROR:**

*Terminated with errorsThe subnet configuration was invalid: The current network ACL rules deny ingress or egress between your subnet and AWS IP address ranges. For more information about the ranges to allow, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/elasticmapreduce/aws_ip_ranges*

Answer (score 0):

The message itself is clear : your ACL rules are using invalid IP, which seem to not be part of your subnet. Here is the authorized AWS IP list
https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

Comment: Please, can I know the what are all the steps I need to follow to get rid of this?

Comment: I could only help you on writing Cisco ACLs rules but I've found this : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_NACLs.html#VPC_Appendix_NACLs_Scenario_1

I think your case in the number 2 but I need more details on how your subnetwork is configured. Are you dealing with IPv4 or IPv6 servers ? If you are doing both, what's your set up ? Dual Stack IP per server, NAT64, 6rd... ?

Answer (score 0):

What I did it to fix was to delete and recreate default vpc and use an older EMR version (emr-5.27.0), still not the best solution but fixed in my case.